# Decrypt AES-256-EAX encrypted string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, aes

I need to decrypt a AES-256-EAX encrypted string from Java in Ruby. 
Ruby's built-in OpenSSL::Cipher provides functionality to decrypt AES-256-CBC, when I try to use AES-256-EAX, its throwing that the algorithm is not supported.

Is there any library/gem out there that decrypts AES-256-EAX string in Ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use CBC on the Java end? And please, encryption is different from encoding.

Comment: Java end is not controlled by me. If I can't find the Ruby implementation for EAX, then my last resort would be to inform the Java end that we (Ruby end) can only support AES-256-CBC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you got the right cipher string ? Googling for "AES-256-EAX" does yield only 8 hits for me and I've never heard of it before. And if OpenSSL doesn't support it you are out if luck, I guess.

Comment: Yes, AES (algorithm) 256 (key-length) and EAX (mode), AES-256-EAX is correct and its possible to decrypt in JAVA. I am trying to find if there is any gem/library that has implemented that in Ruby.

Comment: EAX is a mode for block ciphers, such as AES (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).  It's not that common, probably why it is not part of OpenSSL.  You can put your own decryptor together using just the AES cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to run your ruby code with jruby ?
In this case you could use the java lib inside ruby code to decrypt your string.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not possible, which is why I am trying find the ruby alternatives to that I could re-implement our code in Ruby.